# Remove/disable Kotlin in gradle build

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multimodule gradle project (v6.3 via wrapper)
https://github.com/emeraldpay/polkaj
that keeps saying about
`prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel`.

Kotlin is not used, and all are `.gradle` files, not `.gradle.kts`.

I'd like to remove/disable Kotlin, so that build go faster. And get rid off these messages.

```
> Task :polkaj-api-base:prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
> Task :polkaj-api-http:prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
> Task :polkaj-api-ws:prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
> Task :polkaj-common-types:prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
> Task :polkaj-json-types:prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
> Task :polkaj-scale:prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
> Task :polkaj-scale-types:prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
> Task :polkaj-schnorrkel:prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
> Task :polkaj-ss58:prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
> Task :polkaj-tx:prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
> Task :rpc:prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
> Task :runtime-explorer:prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
> Task :types:prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
```

Comment: As far as I know you can't disable Kotlin in Gradle anymore as Kotlin has become an integral part of Gradle. That, however, should not affect your project much except for these Kotlin-related tasks existing but never doing anything. I agree it would be interesting to be able to disable them as it just "feels" wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this help, in may case, the problem was not with the task `prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel`, but with the **Gradle Reload** action itself in IntellijIdea (Android Studio)

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7633#issuecomment-1176501124

Answer (score 0):

1- delete following lines from `build.gradle(Project)`:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '...'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

2- delete following lines from `build.gradle(Module)`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
```

3- sync your project.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not android project,
and there is no any "kotlin" word within gradle files